# Picasa - Automatically create profile

Tags: android, picasa

I'm programming an Android application which synces pictures to Google Picasa. The problem is that whenever a user wants to upload a picture to his account, but doesn't have the profile created just yet, I get an error about "Unknown user.".

When a visit google picasa web I get the following picture asking me to create a profile:
[image]

Then I have to create a profile in order to be able to upload pictures from an Android phone. But the problem is that I don't want this step to be done by every user manually, which isn't a very good user experience, so I'm asking you if there's a way to automatically create a profile.

So I would present a new Activity to a user saying if we wants to create a profile and if he clicks yes, I would automatically send a GET request to do it. My question is the following: is there any such URI that I can use that would automatically create Google Profile when requested.

I found a link like this, but clicking on it sends me to Google+ page where additional stuff is needed.
https://profiles.google.com/me/createprofile/

The developer's guide doesn't say nothing about this problem: http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingAccount

I guess the other option would be to get the html+javascript+css code of the webpage presented on the picture and showing that in a WebView. The problem is that I can't just use some URL within the WebView, because I also have an OAuth token already and don't want the user to relogin just to create their profile.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Google Sync. Your user already has a Google Account (from market). You could just ask for permission to use his account. Then you can use anything that needs Google account

Comment: Because I need to upload only specific pictures and by using my own code I can do pretty much anything - I'm not limited to the features in Google Sync. And everything already works fine, just need to automatically create Google Profile.